# Jenkins Build Fails when dev commits a change on both parent and child repo simultaneously

Tags: jenkins, mercurial

We are using mercurial 3.7.1 version as a source code repository tool and Jenkins 1.613 as a CI tool.

We have a parent repo and two child repo's. Whenever dev commits a change in parent repo and Jenkins does a build, the build succeeds; when Dev commits a change in one of the child repo, Jenkins does a build and the build also succeeds.

Now the problem: When he commits a changes both on parent repo and child repo, Jenkins build fails saying class not found. Why does this happen?

Parent repo is named as CMS and child repo's are named as DeviceServer and PortalServer.

Is there anything wrong with my build script or in mercurial..?

Here is the screenshot of my Jenkins configuration:
[image]

Below is my Build Script:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 set +e
 #
 # http://jpshu@wtlbuild11-scm:8080/scm/hg/RetailCloudSolution
 #
 date > starttime
 #
 #
 export JAVA_HOME=/home/jenkins/android/jdk1.8.0_51
 export JRE_HOME=/home/jenkins/android/jdk1.8.0_51/jre
 export MAVEN_HOME=/home/jenkins/android/maven/apache-maven-3.2.3
 export M2_HOME=/home/jenkins/android/maven/apache-maven-3.2.3
 ####################################
 # build server
 # export WORKSPACE=/home/jenkins/jenkins/workspace/RetailCloudSolution
 pwd
 mvn -version

echo '####################################'
cd $WORKSPACE/cmsDeviceServer
# mv .properties .properties_orig

 mv WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/couchbase.properties WebContent/WEB-
 INF/classes/couchbase.properties_orig
 mv WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.properties WebContent/WEB-
 INF/classes/log4j2.properties_orig
 mv WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/s3.properties WebContent/WEB-
 INF/classes/s3.properties_orig
 mv WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/elasticsearch.properties WebContent/WEB-
 INF/classes/elasticsearch.properties_orig

 # cp prod/*.properties
 cp $WORKSPACE/cms/src/main/resources/log4j2.properties WebContent/WEBINF/classes/
 cp $WORKSPACE/cms/envConfig/prod/*.properties WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/

  # build DeviceServer.war 
  ###mvn clean compile war:war
  mvn clean compile war:war

  # rm *.properties
  rm WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/couchbase.properties
  rm WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.properties
  rm WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/s3.properties
  rm WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/elasticsearch.properties

  # mv *.properties_orig *.properties

  mv WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/couchbase.properties_orig WebContent/WEB-
INF/classes/couchbase.properties
  mv WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.properties_orig WebContent/WEB-
INF/classes/log4j2.properties
  mv WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/s3.properties_orig WebContent/WEB-
INF/classes/s3.properties
  mv WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/elasticsearch.properties_orig 
WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/elasticsearch.properties

echo '####################################'
echo 'WORKSPACE:'$WORKSPACE
cd $WORKSPACE/cms
### build cms-2.jar
###mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
mvn clean
mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true 


echo '####################################'
cd $WORKSPACE/cmsPortalServer
# mv .properties .properties_orig
mv WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/couchbase.properties WebContent/WEB-
INF/classes/couchbase.properties_orig
mv WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.properties WebContent/WEB-
INF/classes/log4j2.properties_orig
mv WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/s3.properties WebContent/WEB-
INF/classes/s3.properties_orig
mv WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/elasticsearch.properties WebContent/WEB-
INF/classes/elasticsearch.properties_orig

# cp prod/*.properties
cp $WORKSPACE/cms/src/main/resources/log4j2.properties WebContent/WEB-
INF/classes/
cp $WORKSPACE/cms/envConfig/prod/*.properties WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/


# build RESTServer.war 
###mvn clean compile war:war
mvn clean compile war:war

# rm *.properties
rm WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/couchbase.properties
rm WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.properties
rm WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/s3.properties
rm WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/elasticsearch.properties

# mv *.properties_orig *.properties
mv WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/couchbase.properties_orig WebContent/WEB-
INF/classes/couchbase.properties
mv WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.properties_orig WebContent/WEB-
INF/classes/log4j2.properties
mv WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/s3.properties_orig WebContent/WEB-
INF/classes/s3.properties
mv WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/elasticsearch.properties_orig WebContent/WEB-
INF/classes/elasticsearch.properties

echo '####################################'
cd $WORKSPACE
cloc --by-file --exclude-
dir=bin,gen,libs,obj,save,.settings,.kwps,.kwlp,.repo,build,target --
exclude-ext=out,trace --exclude-list-file=$WORKSPACE/../tmp/slocExFile.txt -
-xml -out=build/cloc.xml .
xsltproc $WORKSPACE/../tmp/sloccount.xsl build/cloc.xml > build/my_cloc.sc

cloc --exclude-
dir=bin,gen,libs,obj,save,.settings,.kwps,.kwlp,.repo,build,target --
exclude-ext=out,trace --exclude-list-file=$WORKSPACE/../tmp/slocExFile.txt .

pwd
find . -name *SNAPSHOT.*


ls -l cmsDeviceServer/target/*ar
ls -l cmsPortalServer/target/*ar
```

Comment: What do you mean by "parent" and "child" repo ? These terms do not exist in mercurial.

Comment: @marco.m  
I mean .hg and .hgsubrepo

Comment: We have the one Jar file which I called parent repo(CMS) which has all the server logic and two war files( DeviceServer and PortalServer) which I called children repo's which has the client code .

Comment: can you provide the error message in context?